# How to check for a specific condition by looping through every record in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I do have following table

```
ID  Name 
1   Jagan Mohan Reddy868 
2   Jagan Mohan Reddy869 
3   Jagan Mohan Reddy
```

Name column size is `VARCHAR(55)`.
Now for some other task we need to take only 10 varchar length i.e. `VARCHAR(10)`.
My requirement is to check that after taking the only 10 bits length of Name column value for eg if i take Name value of ID 1 i.e. `Jagan Mohan Reddy868` by `SUBSTRING(Name, 0,11)`  if it equals with another row value. here in this case the final value of `SUBSTRING(Jagan Mohan Reddy868, 0,11)` is equal to Name value of ID 3 row whose Name is 'Jagan Mohan Reddy'. I need to make a list of those kind rows. Can somebody help me out on how can i achieve in SQL Server.

My main check is that the truncated values of my Name column should not match with any non truncated values of Name column. If so i need to get those records.

Comment: I don't understand the question. I can safely say that you do not have those values in a varchar(15) column. There are 20 characters posted. Now if you are only looking for the first 10 characters why does 1 and 3 match but not 2? You could probably do this with a self join but it just isn't very clear what you are trying to do. This article might help get you started. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Your sample data doesn't fit in varchar(15), the longest strings you have are 20 chars in length...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand the question, I think you are looking for something like this:

Create and populate sample data (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T as TABLE
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Name varchar(15)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('Hi, I am Zohar.'),
('Hi, I am Peled.'),
('Hi, I am Z'),
('I''m Zohar peled')
```

Use a cte with a self inner join to get the list of ids that match the first 10 chars:

```
;WITH cte as
(
    SELECT T2.Id As Id1, T1.Id As Id2
    FROM @T T1
    INNER JOIN @T T2 ON LEFT(T1.Name, 10) = t2.Name AND T1.Id <> T2.Id 
)
```

Select the records from the original table, inner joined with a union of the Id1 and Id2 from the cte:

```
SELECT T.Id, Name
FROM @T T
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Id1 As Id
    FROM CTE 
    UNION
    SELECT Id2 
    FROM CTE
) U ON T.Id = U.Id
```

Results:

```
Id          Name
----------- ---------------
1           Hi, I am Zohar.
3           Hi, I am Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Id,Name
FROM(
     SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name, LEFT(Name,11) ORDER BY ID) RN
     FROM Tbale1 T
    ) Tmp
WHERE Tmp.RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

loop over your column for all the values and put your `substring()` function inside this loop and I think in Sql index of string starts from 1 instead of 0. If you pass your string to `charindex()` like this

```
 CHARINDEX('Y', 'Your String')
```

thus you will come to know whether it is starting from 0 or 1
and you can save your substring value as value of other column with length 10

I hope it will help you..

Answer (score 0):

I think this should cover all the cases you are looking for.

```
-- Create Table
DECLARE @T as TABLE
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Name varchar(55)
)

-- Create Data    
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('Jagan Mohan Reddy868'),
('Jagan Mohan Reddy869'),
('Jagan Mohan Reddy'),
('Mohan Reddy'),
('Mohan Reddy123551'),
('Mohan R')

-- Get Matching Items
select *, SUBSTRING(name, 0, 11) as ShorterName
from @T 
where SUBSTRING(name, 0, 11) in 
(
    -- get all shortnames with a count > 1
     select SUBSTRING(name, 0, 11) as ShortName 
     from @T   
     group by SUBSTRING(name, 0, 11)
     having COUNT(*) > 1
)
order by Name, LEN(Name)
```

Comment: This also covers matches where 2 different names will be shortened to the same value.